# express js - How is one http request different from other?

Tags: node.js, http, express, request

I've been working on creating a better architecture for rest api in express and node. Let's say I have 3 methods in my route middleware -

```
router.post('/users/:id', [
  UserService.getUserById,
  UserController.setUser,
  MailerService.sendSubscriptionMail
]);
```

I am setting up req.session.user in call to UserService.getUserById and then using that to set req.session.result in UserController.setUser. Now I am sending a mail to this user using the data stored in req.session.result.

UserService -

```
exports.getUserById = function(req, res, next) {
  .
  .
  req.session.user = data;
  .
  .
};

module.exports = exports;
```

UserController -

```
exports.setUser = function(req, res, next) {
  .
  .
  req.session.result = req.session.user;
  .
  .
};

module.exports = exports;
```

MailerService -

```
exports.sendSubscriptionMail = function(req, res, next) {
  // Using req.session.result here to send email
};

module.exports = exports;
```

Now I have two questions regarding above process -

(a) Is there any chance that a new http req to another route (which also has these kind of methods which can modify req.session) can modify the req.session.result and MailerService.sendSubscriptionMail does not get the data which it needs to send to the user or will that req object will be completely different from this one in the memory?

(b) Is there any other method to transfer data between middleware rather than setting up req object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any chance that a new http req to another route (which also
>   has these kind of methods which can modify req.session) can modify the
>   req.session.result and MailerService.sendSubscriptionMail does not get
>   the data which it needs to send to the user or will that req object
>   will be completely different from this one in the memory?

The `req` object is specific to this request.  That object cannot be changed by another request.  But, if the session in `req.session` is a common shared sesison object that all requests from that particular user share, then `req.session.result` could be changed by another request from that user that is getting processed at around the same time (e.g. interleaved within various async operations).

If you want to make sure that no other request from this user could change your result, then put it in `req.result`, not `req.session.result` because no other requests will have access to `req.result`.

> Is there any other method to transfer data between middleware rather
>   than setting up req object?

The `req` or `res` objects are the right places to share info among middleware handlers for the same request as they are unique to this particular request.  Be careful with the `session` object because it is shared among multiple requests from the same user.

---

Another possible way to share the data among your three handlers is to make a single middleware handler that calls all three of your middleware handlers and then share the data within that single function (e.g. passing it to the other handlers).

For example, you could change the calling signature of your 2nd two methods so you can get the data out of `setUser()` and then pass it directly to `sendSubscriptionMail()` without using the `req` or `session` objects to store it.

```
router.post('/users/:id', [UserService.getUserById, function(req, res, next) {
    UserController.setUser(req, res, function(err, result) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        MailerService.sendSubscriptionMail(result, req, res, next);
    }]);
});
```

Comment: Added another way to do it where you pass the result directly to `MailerService.sendSubscriptionMail()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I want to create a global handler from where I can see all the methods that needs to be called for that particular request because when we call methods inside another method we have to switch between various files to make some changes. Your second idea to create a single middleware handler to call all of them looks wonderful. I'll surely try that.